# SignalR - get list of connected connection ids on the server

Tags: signalr

In my hub, how do I get a list of all currently connected connectionIds?

Essentially, I'm doing some encryption (yes, I've talked to a bunch of people and nothing built-in works) and have an instance of `Aes` for each connection. So basically when I need to send a message to all clients I can't just do `Clients.All` but rather must manually enumerate all clients, fetch its Aes encoder (by id) and then send a message to it.

Comment: Check this [article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections). It's good start what you want to do.

Answer (score 15):

You'll have to build a way to store the connected clients by yourself using OnConnect() and OnDisconnect().

[Get number of listeners, clients connected to SignalR hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514259/get-number-of-listeners-clients-connected-to-signalr-hub)

Comment: Yep, this is what we do.  Also on OnReconnected() we replace clients.  It's basically a Dictionary keyed by Connection ID.  I sure do wish we could access the internal list, but all the docs I have seen indicate that this is how to do it.