# How to get user for every connection?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am authenticating the user using JWT Tokens. Its working correctly, the `Context.User` is populated correctly. The problem is its just one user, does the hub not have a user per connection?

In the `OnNotification` method I want to cycle through all the current connections, verify if the user has permissions to see what I am about to send, then send if he/she has and not otherwise.

How can I acehieve this?

```
  [Authorize]
  public class NotifyHub : Hub {
    private readonly MyApi _api;

    public NotifyHub(MyApi api) {
      _api = api;
      _api.Notification += OnNotification;
    }

    private async void OnNotification(object sender, Notification notification) {
      //  can access Context.User here
      await Clients.All.SendAsync("Notification", notification);
    }
  }
```

Comment: An example of a work-around [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514344/2174170). But you'll use `Context.User` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a Hub you can Invoke methods on the caller client (`Clients.Caller`), one specific client (`Clients.User("client_id")`), a group of clients (`Clients.Group("group name")`), and all the clients (`Clients.All`).

If none of those fit your needs you should implement your own class that tracks the users that are connected to the `Hub` (pretty easy because the Hub has `OnConnectedAsync` and `OnDisconnectedAsync` event handlers for that, I usually do it with a singleton class and a List, and some locks, just for thread safety).

Note that Hubs are transient. They don't exist until they get a request from a client, and immediately disposed after the request finished. So it's not advised to subscribe for events. Hubs are `IDisposable`, so the framework will dispose them after a request finished, so by the time the event arrives they might have been disposed. You should rather inject an `IHubContext<NotifyHub>` (that's what stores the clients of the hub in the memory) into your `MyApi` and use it there with your connected user storing class.

Comment: My hub is added as a singleton `services.AddSingleton<NotifyHub, NotifyHub>();`

Comment: I don't really think that's a great idea, at least I haven't seen anybody doing that :D. For example by making your hub singleton your can't access any scoped services within, and I suppose the resources used by the hub won't be freed either if it's a singleton. Also thread safety can also be a problem if your hub is a singleton.

Comment: But wouldn't it be a performance problem if my hub is created 100 times a second for outgoing job progress updates?

Comment: I don't think it would have been designed that way if it had great impact on the performance.