# How To Refresh Connected ConnectionId List For All The Connected Connection In Blazor Server SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I am trying to refresh the connected `ConnectionId` whenever a new connection is made for all the connected connections in blazor server using signalr.
But the problem is that whenever the second or later connection is made the the same `ConnectionId` is added twice in the list.

Any help with code will be grate. Thank you

Below is my hub

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public Task SendMessage(string ConnectionId, string message)
        {
            return Clients.Client(ConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
           Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveUser", Context.ConnectionId);
           return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
    public static class UserHandler
    {
        public static List<string> ConnectedUsers = new List<string>();
    }
```

Below is my code to refresh connected ConnectionId

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", broad);
        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveUser", RefreshUserList);

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void RefreshUserList(string connectedUserId) // Double hit in this method as a result same connectionId is added twice in the list
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedUsers.Add(connectedUserId);
        connectedUserList = UserHandler.ConnectedUsers;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Use `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<string>`.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514259/get-number-of-listeners-clients-connected-to-signalr-hub solve your problem?