# Shared SignalR HubConnection for multiple BackgroundServices in .NET

Tags: backgroundworker, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-signalr

My .NET BackgroundService application have multple workers and all of them connects to the same SignalR Hub.
Each worker gets a unique ConnectionId which will not work in my case.

How, if possible, can I share the HubConnection between all of the workers to prevent different ConnectionIds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that solves my issue.
I've created a HubService which every worker dependency inject and then calls `EnsureConnectionEstablished()` to make sure the connection is established.

```
public class HubService
{
        private readonly ILogger<SystemHealthWorker> _logger;
        private readonly ConfigurationService _config;
        private HubConnection _connection;

        public HubService(ILogger<SystemHealthWorker> logger, ConfigurationService configService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = configService;
        }

        public async Task<bool> EnsureConnectionEstablished()
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Ensures that the hub connection is established.");

            if (_connection == null || _connection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Hub connection is not established.");

                var config = await _config.GetConfiguration();
                if (config == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.ServerAddress?.ToString()))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid config. Hub connection will not be established.");
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(config.AccessToken))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid access token.");
                }

                var hubUrl = new Uri(config.ServerAddress);
                _logger.LogInformation($"Connecting to hub ({hubUrl})");

                _logger.LogDebug("Building hub connection.");
                _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(hubUrl, options => { options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(config.AccessToken); })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120) })
                .Build();

                _connection.Reconnecting += OnReconnecting;
                _connection.Reconnecting += OnReconnected;
                _connection.Closed += OnClosed;

                await _connection.StartAsync();

                _logger.LogInformation($"Connected to hub with id {_connection.ConnectionId}.");
            }

            return _connection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it appears that each of your workers is connected to SignalR as a client. So the generated `ConnectionId` are different, from the actual development, it is also like this, a real user, may open multiple web pages to establish a connection with the SignalR Hub.

We usually need to use `ConcurrentDictionary` to save information about connected users. For more details, you can [check my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330311/7687666).

The different is you are using C# client, that is using javascript client. But managing connected users in Signalr Hub, this is consistent.

```
public partial class MainHub : Hub
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string?, List<string>>? ConnectedUsers;

    public MainHub()
    {
        ConnectedUsers  = new ConcurrentDictionary<string?, List<string>>();
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {

        //// Get HttpContext In asp.net core signalr
        //IHttpContextFeature hcf = (IHttpContextFeature)this.Context.Features[typeof(IHttpContextFeature)];
        //HttpContext hc = hcf.HttpContext;
        //string uid = hc.Request.Path.Value.ToString().Split(new string[] { "/", "" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].ToString();

        string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
        if (userid == null || userid.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("user not loged in, can't connect signalr service");
            return;
        }
        

        Trace.TraceInformation(userid + "connected");
        // save connection
        List<string>? existUserConnectionIds;
        ConnectedUsers.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
        if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
        {
            existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
        }
        existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        ConnectedUsers.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);

        //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ServerInfo", userid, userid + " connected, connectionId = " + Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, each worker connect to the hub as a client. I save the ConnectionId to the database and pair it with the User through the JWT-token when connecting to the hub. The problem with this is that the ConnectionId will be overwritten for every worker that connects. 

So if I register a handler in Worker 1 (this Worker's ConnectionId is overwritten in the database by later connected workers), this will never be invoked since I use the Id (which is from another worker without the registred handler) in database to invoke the method on the specific client.

Comment: @linusdev You should store the userid instead of the connectionId, that's what I mean in my answer.

Comment: I've solved the issue, added an answer. Thanks for your input!